# select ffplay audio out device

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Hello I have an HDMI out and a USB sound card connected to [pcduino](http://www.pcduino.com) running Ubuntu.

When I run a video through ffplay, the audio out is selected by default as HDMI.

How can I specify or force the out via the usb sound card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **pavucontrol**:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

I found that when I started **ffplay** with an MP3 file, then ran **pavucontrol**, I could switch the output to the USB audio device. Moreover, it remembered the setting on the next run of **ffplay** without affecting other applications, though I have not checked if it remembers after a reboot.

Incidentally, on my Ubuntu 12.10 **ffplay** maps to **avplay**.

Comment: `pavucontrol` only shows a "Dummy output" for me. Alsa works fine.

Answer (score 6):

FFmpeg's ffplay uses SDL libraries, so using SDL environmental variables (SDL_envvars) is possible.

To playback the audio stream through the second audio/card device on your system:

```
$ SDL_AUDIODRIVER="alsa" AUDIODEV="hw:1,0" ffplay
```

A bashrc alias entry:

```
alias ffplay-2ndcard="SDL_AUDIODRIVER='alsa' AUDIODEV='hw:1,0' ffplay"
```

I commonly use the following additional options when playing (AAC) streams:

```
-loglevel info -nodisp -autoexit
```

Comment: Search for `SDL_envvars` to get documentation.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík search where?

Answer (score 0):

If you find **System Settings** -> **Sound**, the first tab (**Output**) allows you to select the output device. This diverts any current and new audio output.

Depending on the release and shell, there are many ways into the sound settings, but I often use what works on most:

- right-click on desk-top and select **Change Desktop Background**;
- press **All Settings**, and the **Sound** settings is in the **Hardware** section.

If you call **ffmpeg** from an application like **VLC media player**, you can set the output device within the preferences, without affecting other applications:

- click **Tools** -> **Preferences** (or **Control-p**);
- under **Audio**, select **ALSA audio output** as the output module;
- you should now find your USB card in the drop-down device list (with a bewildering number of processing options!).

I have just tested VLC outputting through USB speakers while Audacious simultaneously outputs through the laptop speakers (my system sound default).

Comment: The ubuntu version for pcduino doesn't have sound settings. and I would like to do it via commandline if possible

Comment: VLC saves its settings in **~/.config/vlc/vlcrc**. If you want to find where settings are held, you can use the following technique:
`cd ~`
`:>t`
(_Run program and change a setting_)
`:>u`
`find -newer t -not -newer u`
If you do it all quickly there will not be many other files changed. Having found the settings file, you can edit it once you have found out its format (assuming it is text, like VLC's).

Comment: I am using ffplay I cant use vlc :(

Comment: I've not used **ffplay** before, but it's an interesting problem, so I have done some investigations. Despite the huge number of options, I could not find one that didn't give an error when I tried to set the output device. But I did load **pavucontrol**: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`. I started **ffplay** with an MP3 file, then ran **pavucontrol** and I could switch the output to the USB audio device. Moreover, it remembered the setting on the next run of **ffplay** without affecting other apps. This sounds like a solution. Incidentally, on my Ubuntu 12.10 **ffplay** maps to **avplay**.

Comment: I'm very pleased for you. Thanks for the question: I learned quite a lot while pursuing it. I'll add it as an answer so that the question can show up as answered.